# Solr search is returning partial string matches

Tags: java, solr, lucene

Using Solr 3.6.1, I have this field in my schema.xml:

```
<field name="names" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>
<dynamicField name="names_*" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

The documentation in the schema.xml states that "text_general" should:

- tokenize with StandardTokenizer
- removes stop words from case-insensitive "stopwords.txt" (which is currently empty)
- down cases the string.
- At query time only, it also applies synonyms (which is also empty at this time)

I have two documents indexed in Solr with this data for the field:

```
<!-- doc 1 -->
<str name="names_data">Name ABC Dev Loc</str> 

<!-- doc 2 -->
<str name="names_data">Name ABC Dev Location</str>
```

When I execute the following query:

```
id:(doc1 OR doc2) AND names:Dev+Location)
```

Both documents are returned.  I would have expected that only doc2 would have been returned based on my understanding of how Solr's StandardTokenizer works.

Why does "Dev+Location" match "Dev Loc" and "Dev Location"?

Answer (score 2):

The type `text_general` is probably configured to use a [stemmer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming), which is treating `Loc` as a variant of `Location`.

You could configure the type to *not* use a stemmer, or try searching for the whole string using `names:"Dev Location"`

Answer (score 0):

This might be why.

This part of the query `names:Dev+Location` is only searching where `names:Dev` since the `Location` term does not have a field name qualifier it is searching for `Location` against whatever the `<defaultSearchField>` is set to in schema.xml

So you could try to quote the field like `names:"Dev Location"` or prefix it `names:Dev AND names:Location`